# Failed to install laravel

Tags: laravel

I was installing laravel framework by composer in visual studio code. 
composer create-project laravel/laravel ems
but it failed to install the laravel. 
here is the message
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel ems
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.0): Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)    Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/laravel
/zipball/a6c68c24c9938beef0128c3288502b8fbdf8e93d" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: A connection at
tempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection fai
led because connected host has failed to respond.

```
Now trying to download from source
```

- Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.0): Cloning a6c68c24c9 from cache

[RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.
  - https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git
    Cloning into 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ems'...
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Tim
  ed out
  - git@github.com:laravel/laravel.git
    Cloning into 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ems'...
    ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url
 REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-
vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [] [] []

Comment: The repository it is trying to clone is ended with .git/. This is not the url structure for github that any of my tools reference. I believe it should be trying to connect to https://github.com/laravel/laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss something "--prefer-dist"

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectName
```

look at the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5